# Use ceiling function in solver foundation goal?

Tags: solver, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to take the ceiling of one of my decision variables times 2.5, in my Solver goal function, but the Math.Ceiling() function can't be applied because the foobar variable isn't a double, it's a "term" variable.  Is there another way I can express this same code, that will work in Solver?

```
Decision foo = new Decision(Domain.IntegerNonnegative, "bar");
model.AddDecision(foo);

model.AddGoal("foobar", GoalKind.Maximize, Math.Ceiling(2.5 * foobar));
```

Comment: In AddGoal, you're using `foobar`, but you defined the `Decision` variable `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff525471%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) class contains a large number of static methods that performs arithmetic operations on `Term` objects rather than `double`:s. You'll find most, if not all, of the operations that are available in the `Math` class.

In particular, you should be able to change your goal function to use [Model.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.ceiling%28v=vs.93%29.aspx).

Comment: Using the function Model.Ceiling I get the error: 
`No solver could be found that can accept the model given the model type and directive(s)`
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but you have set `foo` to an integer domain decision. What happens if you set `foo` to be a floating-point decision instead?